# PHP Game doesn't recognize location

Tags: php, input

I have a php text-based game that I'm working on, but something's amiss. I can't really describe it, but if I were in Location A and I typed a command "north" to go to Location B, it prints out Location B's details and the appropriate commands for Location B but acts like I were in Location A. So if I typed "north" in Location A and went to Location B and typed "west" in the command box, it would go to the west of Location A, not Location B. To probably better understand this, look at [my (not-working) game](http://urbanadventure.dumpong.tk). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code for the game.

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
print($input);
$World = simplexml_load_file("gameworld.xml");
$CurrentPos = 0;
$Done = 0;
print "<br>";
printplace();
function printplace() {
    GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
    $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
    $Name = $Room->NAME;
    $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
    print "$Name<br>";
    print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
    print "<br>$Desc<br>";
    if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
        print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
        print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
        print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
        print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
}

$input = explode(' ', $input);
print "<br>";
foreach ($input as $command) {
    switch ($command) {
        case 'north':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go north!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'south':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go south!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'west':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go west!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'east':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go east!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'look':
            printplace() ;
            break;
        default:
            print "not a valid command... <br>";
            break;
    }
}
print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't persist your $CurrentPos between calls to the page.

Comment: ^ this. $CurrentPos is set to 0 every page load. Use session/cookie/get parameters

Comment: is this a multiplayer or a single player game?

Comment: Sessions don't seem to be working for me (I'm probably doing it wrong, I'm a newbie to PHP). I don't know how to persist $CurrentPos, either...

Comment: This is a single player game.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me, you should really try posting code or a screenshot so it lasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about PHP session handling: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Your game parameters (like `$CurrentPos`) are reset for every new request. You will need to persist the game's state between requests. Sessions are made to do just that.

Try something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['CurrentPos'])) {
    $_SESSION['CurrentPos'] = 0;
}
$CurrentPos = $_SESSION['CurrentPos'];
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this wrong, but either sessions don't work for me or I'm applying it to the wrong variable. What I did was that I started the session with `session_start();` and then I used `$CurrentPos = $_SESSION["CurrentPos"] = 0 ;` to set $CurrentPos as a session variable. I don't think I'm doing this correctly, though.

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of how setting the current position should work with sessions.